# Where can I promote Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, promoting

I am currently writing a FOSS Rails app and would like to get some ideas about where to promote the application. I am searching for something like opensourcerails.com or wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/OpenSourceProjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also post to these sites:

http://www.rubyflow.com/

http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/

Let these guys know about your projects, too:

http://railsenvy.com/

Answer (score 4):

Put it on github, too - it's social, Rails-oriented and free repos have to be open-source.

Edit: I'd get in touch with the leading blogs about it, then. They'll get word out way faster than if it's simply sitting on a static list of projects.

Answer (score 3):

Don't promote it as a Rails application. Promote it as an application that solves whatever problem your application is meant to solve. I doubt there are very many people who sit around thinking, "Boy, I'd sure like to run a Rails application. I wonder what app I could run." Rather, they think something like, "Boy, I sure wish there were a FOSS liveblogging app with Twitter integration."

Answer (score 2):

Try finding the people who would benefit from using your application and tell them about it.

Answer (score 1):

Working With Rails has a showcase section (previously HappyCodr)

http://workingwithrails.com/browse/sites/showcase

You need to create a profile to add your project

Comment: Thank you! That was one of those sites I forgot the name of :)

Comment: your welcome, I always visit that site to check on new rails projects

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the people who do various rails podcasts to give it a mention.

Answer (score 0):

Announce it on the [rubyonrails-talk mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk) where people from all around the world subscribe to. From there, if you keep doing good things the word-of-mouth should spread it around.

If we knew what your app *did* we could be more precise about where to put these kinds of things.